# 'Gravity' does not contain a definition for 'CENTER_HORIZONTAL'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

So I am trying to make a toast error message appear in the center of the screen. Both horizontally and vertically so I found a solution but when viewing the Gravity declaration I do not see any of the CENTER_HORIZONTAL or CENTER_VERTICAL methods. Could this be an issue with the version of Android that I am using? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Toast error = Toast.MakeText(this, "Please check your internet connection.", ToastLength.Long);
error.SetGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
error.Show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xamarin.Android, you are looking for the `GravityFlags` enum:

```
error.SetGravity(GravityFlags.CenterVertical | GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal, 0, 0);
```